# mysql update table with values within table

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table with this structure

```
table: WP_ICL_TRANSLATIONS
translation_id | element_type | element_id | trid | language_code | source_language_code
18               post_page      15           14     en              Null
427              post_page      1228         14     zh-hans         en
20               post_page      17           15     en              Null
166              post_page      228          15     zh-hans         en
```

and another table like this:

```
table: WP_POSTMETA
ID   | post_content
15     english content... 
1228   chinese content... 
17     english content... 
228    chinese content...
```

What I need to do is update the field `post_content` in english with the content in chinese.
The posts relation is stored in the first table using the field `trid`

So, if i want to update the record with id 15 in WP_POSTMETA i have to go to the `WP_ICL_TRANSLATIONS` table and search for another id with the same `trid`  and then get that id.With that id i can update the `WP_POSTMETA` table .

What i have now its a select to get the corresponding chinese ID for a english ID:

```
select element_id from wp_icl_translations where trid=(select trid from wp_icl_translations where element_id=779) and element_id<>779;
```

but i have to enter the id manually.

Is it possible a query to do that update? maybe using a temporal table?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
UPDATE WP_POSTMETA p1, WP_POSTMETA p2
     , WP_ICL_TRANSLATIONS t1, WP_ICL_TRANSLATIONS t2
   SET p1.post_content = p2.post_content
 WHERE t1.trid = t2.trid
   AND t1.element_id = p1.ID
   AND t2.element_id = p2.ID
   AND t1.language_code = 'en'
   AND t2.language_code = 'zh-hans'
```